# InfoPath to Outlook compatibility (2010)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, visual-studio, email, infopath-data-connections

I have created an InfoPath (2010) form to use for a weekly update. The user submits the details in the repeating fields and the form submits to a SharePoint List and it should submit to Email. The problem however, is that the email does not display correctly and the formatting is off.

I have tried to use alternatives such as SharePoint Designer or making a workflow through Visual Studio (2010). I want the data submitted into the form to show up in the Email. Is there any way to do this through C#?

*this is what my emails from an InfoPath submit look like*
[image]
Thanks